# arangodb wal/logfile/journal/datafile relations

Tags: arangodb

- installed Arangodb 3.1 single instance
- have years of dba experience with rdbms, and some experience with non-sql also
- read the arangodb manual, but still confused about the relations between journal, datafile, logfile and wal. Where each of them is located, how named, when created/purged, etc.

  Is there any single document which explains the relations between those basic entities ?

Best regards,
Avi

Answer (score 0):

The ArangoDB MM-Files engine works this way:

- it keeps a memory mapped WAL-files, into which documents are put. System calls are used to ensure certain parts of the file were actually stored to disk.
- in idle-times, documents are moved from the WAL-Files into their respective collection files.
- once you delete a document, a delete marker is written.
- an update first writes this delete marker, then creates the new document.
- the collection process runs over the database files, and joins delete markers and their respective documents - so the document is finally gone.
- several collection files may be joined together by the compactor, so the number of open files can be maintained stable.

ArangoDB 3.2 onwars you also can choose the rocksdb storage engine, which has its own mechanisms in place.